# Using bordered Hessian matrix to determine non-degeneracy and type of constrained extremum

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, calculus-of-variations

I have the following problem: $\def\f{f(x_1,x_2,x_3)}\def\1{x_1}\def\2{x_2}\def\3{x_3}\def\n{\nabla}\def\g{g(x_1,x_2,x_3)}\def\l{\lambda}\def\q{\begin{pmatrix}}\def\p{\end{pmatrix}}$

> Find the critical points of the following constrained optimization problem:
> $$\f=\1^2+\2^2+2\3^2$$
> subject to $$\g=\1+\2+\3=4$$

and am required to check that these are non-degenerate and need to determine local min and maxima.

---

$$L = \f+\l \g$$
$$=\1^2+\2^2+2\3^2+\l\1+\l\2+\l\3-4$$
$$\n L= (2\1+\l,2\2+\l,4\3+\l)=\vec{0}$$
Which yields:
$$\1+\2+\3=4 \;\; (1)$$
$$2\1+\l=0 \;\;(2)$$
$$2\2+\l=0\;\;(3)$$
$$4\3+\l=0\;\;(4)$$

From 2),3), $\1=\2$,from 4),$\3=\frac{\2}2$

From 1) $\frac52\2=4\Rightarrow \2=\frac85$

$$\1=\frac85=\2,\3=\frac8{10},\l=-5$$

> $f(\frac85,\frac85,\frac8{10})=\frac{32}{5}$
>
> To check degeneracy, I have to look at the bordered Hessian matrix.
>
> Can someone show me how to use this bordered Hessian matrix?

My attempt:
$$ H = \q 0 & g_{\1} & g_{\2} & g_{\3} \\ g_{\1}&L_{{\1}{\1}}&L_{{\1}{\2}}&L_{{\1}{\3}} \\ g_{\2}&L_{{\2}{\1}}&L_{{\2}{\2}}&L_{{\2}{\3}} \\ g_{\3}&L_{{\3}{\1}}&L_{{\3}{\2}}&L_{{\3}{\3}}  \p $$

$$ H = \q 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1&2&0&0 \\ 1&0&2&0 \\ 1&0&0&4  \p $$

Taking the determinant of this yields $ H = -14 \ne 0$ Hence this is not a degenerate point.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/726473/) which has correct bordered Hessian for similar functions.

Comment: @Thursday Thank you for that, if possible, could you verify my answer?

Comment: I don't think that saying $H\ne 0$ is enough; the bordered Hessian requires consideration of upper-left minors of certain sizes, as described in [Bordered Hessian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian) article. Here $m=1$ and $n=3$, so you check the signs of $3\times 3$ minor (negative) and the full matrix (also negative). Conclusion: minimum. ... For the future: observe that *searching* can lead to useful information faster than typing the question.

Comment: @Thursday searching *can* lead to useful information faster, but verification it (usually) cannot.

Comment: @Thursday Thank you for title edit. I will refer to your helpful link and will in future refer to the search function more readily.

Comment: @Thursday Suprisingly(or not) I had never heard of the term minor etc. So here I am looking at $\det$ along $g_{x_2}$ since it is at $M_{1,3}$?

Comment: Upper left minor of size $3$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1&2&0 \\ 1&0&2  \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Thursday So I take the upper left minor, I see, and I take the det of the entire matrix. If both are negative I am certain it is a minimum. In the case of two constraints $g_1$ and $g_2$, I have to take the $3\times3$ uper left minor and the $4\times4$ uper left minor and the full $H$ finally, correct?

Comment: (That was me mis-clicking; I don't really use chat.) Quote from Wikipedia: "the smallest minor consisting of the truncated first 2m+1 rows and columns, the next consisting of the truncated first 2m+2 rows and columns, and so on, with the last being the entire bordered Hessian. There are thus n–m minors to consider." So, with $n=3$ variables and $m=2$ constraints you would have a size $5$ bordered Hessian, and only the sign of the whole thing would need to be checked ($(2m+1)=5$).

Comment: @Thursday Thank you very much, you are extremely helpful. I understand now!

Comment: @Thursday One final question. My lecturer uses an alternative bordered hessian(for whatever reason), $H = \begin{bmatrix} H_L & B\\B^T & 0\end{bmatrix}$ I imagined that this would just mean I take the bottom right minor instead of the top left and perhaps this has similar results, but it would seem that it has a different result here:$\begin{vmatrix}2&0&1\\0&4&1\\1&1&0\end{vmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, you take bottom right corner. The value is different, but the sign is the same, and so is the conclusion. This change has the same effect as relabeling the variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$ to $x_3,x_2,x_1$. The appearance of Hessian changes (since the row and columns  are rearranged) and the minors don't have the same values as before, but the theory applies the same.

Comment: @Thursday Okay, that makes sense. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand at the first line
$\det H = -\det\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 & 0\\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 &0 & 4\end{pmatrix}+\det\begin{pmatrix}1 &2 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 &0 & 4\end{pmatrix}-\det\begin{pmatrix}1 &2 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 &0 & 0\end{pmatrix}=-8-8-4=-20$

Comment: I see, I accidently took $-1*4 + 4*[-2-2]=-20$ as $-1*4 + 4*-2 -2=-14$